# Codeigniter Model extending - Fatal error: Class 'MY_Basedbclass' not found in

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-2

I know there are other similar questions, but even after following all the syntax, this errror exists

**I am using Codeigniter version 2.1.4 on wamp server, windows 7.**

in `application/core/` i have `MY_Basedbclass.php` starting with

```
abstract class MY_Basedbclass extends CI_Model
{
```

and trying to use it in my mode like

```
class Accounts_manager extends MY_Basedbclass 
{
```

ending up with the error - `Fatal error: Class 'MY_Basedbclass' not found in C:\wamp\www\party_app\server\application\models\accounts_manager.php`

Please suggest what i am doing wrong. Thanks

**EDIT - Addign a screen shot for the file structure sake**

[image]

Comment: Have you included the MY_Basedbclass file?

Comment: i have tried the including in the beginning of the file like this `include_once BASEPATH.'../application/models/basedbclass.php';` and then simple extend with the class name, still says not found

Comment: include_once but do not use basepath, you need to allow it from the php.ini if i recall correctly. That said, try to access the file without basepath and see if it resolve.

Comment: What is the value of `$config['subclass_prefix']` in your config file?

Comment: `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` this is the line in the config file

Comment: @Goikiu please suggest me how i can include a model directory in the php.ini file and use it in the model. `include_path = ".;c:\php\includes" ` is currently existing.

Comment: @Goikiu i have included this `include_path='.;c:\php\includes;c:\wamp\www\attendance\application\models";` in the php.ini and trying `include_once 'basedbclass.php';` in the beginning of the model file, and the class extends as `class Accounts_manager extends Basedbclass {`, the class i am extending is `abstract class Basedbclass extends CI_Model
{` placed in the models folder.

Comment: @Archer Have you tried putting all the file needed in the same folder and include_once them from there? There are any changes?

Comment: @Goikiu well, this is the only file i have till now, and including the first time, and i am stuck like this. `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: include_once(basedbclass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: models/accounts_manager.php` and `Severity: Warning

Message: include_once(): Failed opening 'basedbclass.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\php\includes;c:\wamp\www\attendance\application\models)`

Comment: can you put into your question the file structure?

Comment: @Goikiu added an image, for the file structure.

Comment: Tried some including relative? include_once 'basedbclass.php';

Comment: yes, tried relative also tried ./basedbclass.php, not working.

Comment: put into your question the include_once code for the file =) It can help you find the correct answer.

Comment: @Goikiu Thank you for your support, the answer by Majid below was the issue, need to use only **MY_Model** to extend.

Comment: @Archer man :D you need to activate your windows OS joking )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why you define your core model class as **abstract** class? after that you can only set core model class as `MY_Model`. this name get from `subclass_prefix + class_name_you_want_to_over_write`

define your core class like this:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
 // your code
 }
```

before that assured in your **config.php** file you set `$config['subclass_prefix'] =` to `MY_`

**config file address: application > config > config.php**

Comment: well, i have removed the **abstract** but it still is the same. Is "MY_Model" name important, unlike the new class that i am using "MY_Basedbclass"?

Comment: yes, it's important. please see this tutorial http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Thank you, yes, that was the issue.

Comment: Thanks Majid, In my case My Model name was class My_Model, Where y is in smaller case it worked perfectly in windows and when I went to Linux it blast. I struggled a lot and after reading your Answer came to know that in my config.php filet $config['subclass_prefix'] =  MY_ where Y is upper case. After changing to smaller case in config it rocked.

Comment: @prashantthakre , Linux or FreeBSD OS are case sensitive so this little note create an issue for you. I'm really happy that i can help you with this answer